# Cant change a '(not completely) global variable' from a function javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like teacherID to be returned from this function so I defined the variable outside the function the actual value is created but it doesn't seem to be working any help? (P.S. Was not sure what this sort of variable is called )

```
function getTeacherID(courseID,block,roomID){
    //Get the rooms for the subjects the student does
    var teacherID;
    function doXHRPromise() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    resolve(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            var everythingArray = [courseID,block,roomID];
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getTeacherIDTimetable.php?q=" + JSON.stringify(everythingArray), true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        });
    }
    doXHRPromise().then(function(responseText) {
        teacherID = responseText;
    });
    return teacherID;
}
```

Comment: Your then runs after you've returned the value. Its still async. Just return the promise and attach a then in your calling code.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: callback maybe?

Comment: You could wait for resolve the async method by calling `Promise.resolve(object)` :) But this is bad practice at all

Comment: @Kyon: That won't do anything.

Comment: @SLaks I know it's the same like using `.then()`

Comment: I have looked at the question that this is meant to be a duplicate of and it does not help at all

Comment: You need to return and use the promise.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/

Comment: @SLaks How do you return the promise?